# Killing everything except for a certain player in a certain radius

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How can I kill or teleport everyone in a 20 block radius except for me and my friend. Our usernames are `bob8898` and `coach0512`. I was thinking that `/kill {radius 20, type=!bob8898, type=!coach0512}` might work. Is this possible?

Comment: Try looking at this: http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands#Target_selector_arguments

Comment: The syntax of your command is wrong. You can't have spaces in between commas, and the curly braces should be replaced with square brackets. `radius 20` should also be changed to `r=20`

Comment: @EthanBierlein not to mention, it needs to be a selector (ex. @p, @e)

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to be excluded from a global selector, simply use a scoreboard to exempt yourselves.
This is due to the way entity selectors work, which does not allow you to specify specific players.

```
/scoreboard objectives add noKill dummy noKill
```

Now, tag yourselves for not killing, and run this in a 20Hz redstone clock, in the order it is provided:

```
/scoreboard players set @e noKill 0
/scoreboard players set [Your username] noKill 1
     <Repeat for as many players>
/kill @e[score_noKill=0,score_noKill_min=0,r=100]
```

This way, you're marking everybody to be killed, exempting yourselves (by not making your score 0 and setting it 0 or nothing) then killing those who hasn't been exempted yet.

You can add more to the exemption list by adding a block with the following command before the last and after the first command blocks:

```
/scoreboard players set <Selectors and modifiers> noKill 1
```

**Note:** I may have gotten the syntax a bit wrong.

Comment: Although, I'm pretty sure inverting the `name` modifier  with an `!` on selectors will target all except the specific player, but I'm not too sure about specifying multiple players in the command.

Comment: Your method kills everything *but* Player 1, then it kills everything *but* Player 2, and the problem with that: Both players get killed anyhow, just not at the same time (presuming there's a delay between both commands). | Whenever you run commands, think of it as instructions. If they can be run with a 10 second delay between them, then it should work.

Comment: Then is it possible to make sure that nobody can edit the scoreboard?

Comment: It's as easy as: Be "not op'd"... Besides, since it's run on a clock, edits would only last for less than a tick before being reverted back to the values specified by the rules.

Comment: There, fixed your syntax.

Comment: Wow.. I actually got Minecraft confused with VB/C#...

Answer (score 1):

/kill {radius 20, type=!bob8898, type=!coach0512} is very close, but this is how you do it:

/kill @e[r=20, type=!Player]

This will kill everything but players.

To do this if you are on a server with more than 2 people, we will use teams.
this is a slightly easier way to do it than using scoreboard variables.

/scoreboard teams add noTeleport noTeleport

/scoreboard teams join noTeleport bob8898 coach0512

/kill @e[r=20, team=!noTeleport]

Comment: Can you test your second command? I'm almost positive the type tag does not allow player names.

Comment: Plus, the existence of 2 players guarantees it is multiplayer.

Comment: it could be lan... i will test it.

Comment: but that would be multiplayer. i just meant a server.

Comment: It is going to be on a server. I want it so that nobody, even other ops, cannot access a certain room.

Comment: @Bob8898 but you want YOU and coach to NOT be able to access a room?

Comment: @Judge2020 do you think the name tag would work?

Answer (score 1):

`/kill @e[type=!Player,r=1000]` should work

Answer (score 1):

@Bob8898 If you want it to be a certain room only you can access put a command block on with a loop (Hopper Clock, Comparator Clock, etc)

```
/tp @e[r=(Enter Radius Here), type=!(Username)] (X Coordinate) (Y Coordinate) (Z Coordinate)
```

In 1.9 you can put the Always active function on and enter this command. If you want more players just repeat the Type variable.

Answer (score 1):

Invert the name selector twice, using both your usernames. `@a[name=!playerone,name=!playertwo]` means not playerone or playertwo.